# Basic question about nonstandard derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I'm trying to understand how the nonstandard derivative works.

For instance, consider the function

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^2$

The derivative is

$f'(x) = st \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x + \epsilon)^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^2}{\epsilon} \right)$

for some infinitesimal $\epsilon$. This works out to

$f'(x) = st(x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) = st(x)$

So the derivative of $\frac{1}{2} x^2$ is the standard part function.

Is this correct? I was expecting the derivative to be $f'(x) = x$ instead. $st(x)$ doesn't even have the same domain as the original function. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-standard definition of derivatives that you quote in your question defines the ordinary derivative function, mapping real numbers $x$ to real numbers $f'(x)$.  Here $f$ itself should also be an ordinary function mapping real numbers to real numbers.  Where the definition appears to apply $f$ to a non-standard input, $x+\varepsilon$, it ought to apply not the ordinary $f$ but rather its canonical extension, usually called ${}^*\!f$, which takes hyperreals to hyperreals.

Comment: Aha! Ok, that makes sense. Do people ever work with hyperreal-valued functions of a hyperreal variable as useful objects of study of their own right?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Yes, but if you work with hyperreal functions of a hyperreal variable then their derivatives have to be introduced either by the standard $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition interpreted in the hyperreal world or by a non-standard definition involving hyper-hyper-reals.

Comment: Or by applying transfer to the standard derivative.

Answer (score 4):

$$f'(x) = st \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x + \epsilon)^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^2}{\epsilon} \right)= st \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \epsilon x + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^2}{\epsilon} \right) \\ = st \left( \frac{\epsilon x + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2}{\epsilon} \right) = st \left( x + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\right)=x$$

Note that the standard part function is a function from the hyperreals to the reals. We can just evaluate it, since $x$ is real. Since $\epsilon$ is extremely small, $x$ is the nearest real number. (I assume that you want the derivative with domain $\mathbb R$, not with the hyperreals as domain)

Comment: I thought that in hyperreal analysis the functions all have hyperreal domain. If not, how would it make sense to evaluate $f(x)$ at $x+\epsilon$ to begin with?

Comment: I thought that in NSA, we work with hyperreal extensions of functions as governed by the transfer principle. Since the derivative involves us evaluating $f(x)$ at a hyperreal value, I assumed that's what we were working with. So as far as hyperreal functions go, $st(x) \neq x$ in the hyperreals, and it's also defined only for those hyperreals that are finite. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia What you're missing is that the usual definition of the derivative is for building a derivative $f' : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ from a function $f : \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}^*$ (which is usually the natural extension of some function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$). If you want to enlarge the domain then you should take the natural extension of this result.